# window.open createElement('form') with submit input type is not calling the action

Tags: javascript, window.open, createelement

I am trying to open a new window with a custom form in javascript

In the form I am having some fields and action along with the submit input (please note that the element should be of input type=submit

However, when clicking the submit button in the popup window, the submit action is not performed.

```
    var map = window.open("","editormap",'width=600,height=600,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');
    
        var mapForm = map.document.createElement('form');
        mapForm.target = "editormap";
        mapForm.id="inpForm";
        mapForm.method = "POST"; 
        mapForm.action = "/dashboard/save/"+val1+"/"+val2;
    
      var mapInput3 = map.document.createElement('input');
      mapInput3.type = 'submit';
      mapInput3.name = 'submit';
      mapInput3.value = 'Submit';
      mapForm.appendChild(mapInput3);
    
       var  mapInput = map.document.createElement('input');
        mapInput.type = "button";
        mapInput.name = "cancel";
        mapInput.value = "Cancel";
        mapInput.onclick=map.close;
        mapForm.appendChild(mapInput);
        
    
      var  mapInput1 = map.document.createElement("textarea");
        mapInput1.name = "code";
        mapInput1.value = repoValues;
        mapForm.appendChild(mapInput1);
        
     var mapInput2 = map.document.createElement("input");
     mapInput2.type = "hidden";
    mapInput2.name = "filename";
    mapInput2.value = 'some data';
    mapForm.appendChild(mapInput2);
    
   map.document.body.appendChild(mapForm);
```

I have also tried bind like below

```
var parentForm = document.createElement.bind(document);
var mapForm = parentForm('form');
```

still the submit is not performing the requested action.

Please help or guide in the right direction.

Comment: Not related to the submit button: `mapInput.onclick=map.close;` should be `mapInput.onclick=map.close.bind(map);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the window has an empty location, relative URLs have no base URL to be interpreted relative to. So you need to provide the full URL in the `action` URL.

```
        mapForm.action = "https://www.example.com/dashboard/save/"+val1+"/"+val2;
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/3fzoaptw/8/)

(Stack Snippets don't allow popup windows, so I had to use jsfiddle for the demo.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Based on your input I had the full path provided rather than only the relative path. It worked. However, The controller had POST mapping for /dashboard/save url still the action was not performed. Only by specifying the full path the action was performed. If you have any insights to the reason please share

Comment: It's because the new window has an empty location URL, so relative URLs have nothing to expand on. I've updated the answer.